# ruby on rails migrations using an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have this problem. I need to use an existing table on a mysql database. The name of the table is not compatible with RoR conventions and I need to remap the table name and the name of the attributes. I have created a scaffold to visualize on a web page the content of the table but I can't change the mapping. Is there a solution to indicate to RoR the relation between the name of the class and the name  of the table in the database? and a solution to indicate the relation between the attribute of the class and field on the table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The table name can be specified using [table_name](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name) class method.

For the attributes/column, you need to explicitly specify aliases for the attributes using [alias_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-alias_attribute) method. For example, if you have `name_of_thing` column, but want to treat it as `name`, then you need something like this in your model:

```
class CreateUtenti < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "another_name"
  alias_attribute :name, :name_of_thing
end
```

Comment: Thanks to you too. In this case rake db:migrate give me this error: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `table_name=' for CreateUtenti:Class

Comment: @GiovanniDiClemente does your CreateUtenti class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: what Rails version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass table name in model like:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "pass_table_name_here"
end
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have tried but rake db:migrate give me an error: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Comment: Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Macintosh:telwebtt giovannidiclemente$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)